# Calling user defined function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am try to define a function in MATLAB. Then I want to use this function in some other program. The code is as follows:

```
function E = maxadd(n,m,A,B) 

n = input ('Enter the no. of rows of matrix A or B : '); 

m = input ('Enter the no. of columns of matrix A or B : '); 

A = input ('enter the matrix A, n*m : ');

B = input ('enter the matrix B, n*m : ');

D = -Inf(n,m);

for i=1:n     %addition of matrices

  for j=1:m

      D(i,j)=max (A(i,j), B(i,j));

  end;

end;

E = D ;

end
```

The program runs ok but, if I run `maxadd(2,2,[1 2;3 4],[0 4 ;3 7])` in the command window, it asks me for input again instead of giving me an answer.

Please help me in fixing this issue. My file name is `maxadd.m`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't make this clear, but I'm guessing you're trying to write a function that takes optional arguments over the default behavior of asking the user for it. If so, you need to explicitly write the logic in your function, like this:

```
function E = maxadd(n,m,A,B) 

%//prompt user for values if they weren't passed as parameters
if nargin < 1
    n = input ('Enter the no. of rows of matrix A or B : '); 
end
if nargin < 2
    m = input ('Enter the no. of columns of matrix A or B : '); 
end
if nargin < 3
    A = input ('enter the matrix A, n*m : ');
end
if nargin < 4
    B = input ('enter the matrix B, n*m : ');
end

%//your logic here

end
```

This checks how many input arguments the caller specified, and requests the missing parameters accordingly.

However, we can do better than this.

---

Typically when we request input from the user, we should always assume that the user can screw up and give us non-sense input. Thus, it is good practice to always check your inputs.

In your case, the first 2 parameters should be numbers, and the last 2 parameters should be matrices, so we check them like this:

```
function E = maxadd(n,m,A,B) 

%//prompt user for values if they weren't passed as parameters
if nargin < 1
    n = input ('Enter the no. of rows of matrix A or B : '); 
end
if nargin < 2
    m = input ('Enter the no. of columns of matrix A or B : '); 
end
if nargin < 3
    A = input ('enter the matrix A, n*m : ');
end
if nargin < 4
    B = input ('enter the matrix B, n*m : ');
end

%//validate input
if ~isnumeric(n)
    error('Input parameter n must be numeric');
elseif ~isnumeric(m)
    error('Input parameter m must be numeric');
elseif ~ismatrix(A)
    error('Input parameter A must be a matrix');
elseif ~ismatrix(B)
    error('Input parameter B must be a matrix');
end


%//your logic here

end
```

But we can improve this further. Notice that `n` and `m` are really properties of matrices `A` and `B`, and notice that both matrices really need to be the same dimensions for your algorithm to work. Combining this knowledge, we minimize the code like this:

```
function E = maxadd(A,B) 

%//prompt user for values if they weren't passed as parameters
if nargin < 1
    A = input ('enter the matrix A, n*m : ');
end
if nargin < 2
    B = input ('enter the matrix B, n*m : ');
end

%//validate input
if ~ismatrix(A)
    error('Input parameter A must be a matrix');
elseif ~ismatrix(B)
    error('Input parameter B must be a matrix');
elseif ~isequal(size(A), size(B))
    error('Matrices A and B must have the same dimensions')
end

n = size(A, 1);
m = size(A, 2);

%//your logic here

end
```

---

Finally, I would like to point out 2 things:

1. `max` already does what you're trying to do. Calling `max(A,B)` will give you the same output
2. `E` isn't necessary at all. If you change the output variable to `D` and remove the line `E = D;`, the code will work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well for the first part 
 Your code

```
function E = maxadd(n,m,A,B)

n = input ('Enter the no. of rows of matrix A or B : ');

m = input ('Enter the no. of columns of matrix A or B : ');

A = input ('enter the matrix A, n*m : ');

B = input ('enter the matrix B, n*m : ');
```

your code has one problem either ask the user for the input or pass the values yourself so you can just use 
function E = maxadd(n,m,A,B) just pass the values from the command window and thats it 
no need for this part

```
n = input ('Enter the no. of rows of matrix A or B : ');

    m = input ('Enter the no. of columns of matrix A or B : ');

    A = input ('enter the matrix A, n*m : ');

    B = input ('enter the matrix B, n*m : ');
```

Comment: I tried removing four input lines. But on compilation it is giving an error. It says that "Input argument 'n' is undefined".

Comment: n is defined in your function input the input could be be like this maxadd(1,1,[2],[3]) here n =1 this should work i guess

Answer (score 0):

You are already passing n, m, A and B as input argument of the maxadd function. You are not supposed to ask for the same values inside the function. If you want the input to be called inside the function, do something similar to this:

```
function E = maxadd() 

n = input ('Enter the no. of rows of matrix A or B : '); 

m = input ('Enter the no. of columns of matrix A or B : '); 

A = input ('enter the matrix A, n*m : ');

B = input ('enter the matrix B, n*m : ');

D = -Inf(n,m);

for i=1:n     %addition of matrices

  for j=1:m

      D(i,j)=max (A(i,j), B(i,j));

  end;

end;

E = D ;

end
```

And when you call it:

```
>> maxadd
Enter the no. of rows of matrix A or B : 2
Enter the no. of columns of matrix A or B : 2
enter the matrix A, n*m : rand(2,2)
enter the matrix B, n*m : rand(2,2)

ans =

    0.8147    0.2785
    0.9058    0.9134
```

---

If you don't want to change all calls to the `maxadd` function, just modify it like that :

```
function E = maxadd(n, m, A, B) 

D = -Inf(n,m);

for i=1:n     %addition of matrices

  for j=1:m

      D(i,j)=max (A(i,j), B(i,j));

  end;

end;

E = D ;

end
```

Comment: What I am trying to say is that, I want to define this function because I have to use this function in some other program at so many stage. So that's why I am using the command "maxadd(n,m,A,B)". 
But If I remove all four input line while keeping this function definition there it's gives an error and if I keep these input lines as well then it asks for input again even if I give command of this type "maxadd(2,2,[1 2;0 3],[0 3, 2 4])". I hope now you understand my problem.

Comment: Well if you don't want to change all the calls to that function, just remove the `n`, `m`, `A` and `B` lines (the ones calling the `input` function).